# Arrows in R Studio Server

Tags: r, rstudio-server

In our RStudio Server, the navigation arrows to move through columns of a data frame (when there are more than 50 columns) show up as [boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd6X5.png) instead of [arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQxEx.png).

We are running RStudio 1.4.1717 on RHEL 7. How do we fix this?

Comment: What is the system locale?

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C`

Comment: Can you try ```Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "en_US.UTF8");
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "English_United States.utf8");
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE", locale = "English_United States.utf8");
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_COLLATE", locale = "en_US.UTF8")```, followed by refresh/restart